# Assign value if argument is correct - otherwise do nothing R

Tags: r

```
data = c(1,2,3,5,6)
```

How can I create a new column that will assign a number - if argument is correct ? For example if data >3 it will give the new column value 1. And the result will be

```
1
2
3
4 1
5 1
6 1
```

I don't want anything to happen with the first 3 as I will assign them other numbers. I thought I could do this with `ifelse` command and put NA, but the problem was that I just kept overwriting my data. I´m searching for something similar as `ifelse`, but only if, and nothing else :)

Comment: `cbind(1:6,ifelse((1:6)>3,1,NA))` doesn't seem to overwrite data

Comment: You say "column" as if this were a `data.frame`. Is your intended use with a vector, matrix, or data.frame?

Comment: as data.frame. The problem if I use cbind(1:6,ifelse((1:6)>3,1,NA)) and after that want to assign <2 the number 2 by using (1:6,ifelse((1:6)<2,2,NA)) It will overwrite the first "ones" with NA.

Comment: For the second assignment do `df[,2]<-ifelse(df[,1]<2,2,df[,2])`

Comment: I just made that date set as an example. I have 25 different numbers that I need to assign different numbers. I looking something similar as ifelse, but :

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to etienne the answer is to use ifelse and assign its current value if "else".